# System prefers not to use the index

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table Relations(Friend,minutes) where minutes is uniformly distributed in the interval [0; 500]. Consider a
query with the condition B ≥ 250. To optimize this query, i created a non-clustered index on minutes. However, the system prefers not to use the index. Why?

Friend is the primary key

Comment: Cardinality - google it. Without the query, number of records and output of `EXPLAIN` - it's guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Your query condition is not selective. It touches half of the records. The query optimizer thinks table scan is the better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main purposes of an index in a query is to reduce the number of data pages that are being accessed.  Each data page typically contains many records -- dozens or hundreds.

Using an index incurs overhead:

- The index pages need to be read into memory.
- The associated data pages also need to be read into memory.
- The data pages are not accessed in order, which can result in thrashing in low-memory (big data) circumstances.

If you are accessing half the records, then you are still accessing all the data pages.  As a result, the database optimizer decides that it is cheaper to read them all and do the comparison, rather than invoking the index.

What can you do?  One option is to make an index that *covers* your query.  That is, instead of indexing `(minutes)`, index `(minutes, friend)`.  Because all columns are in the index, the data pages do not need to be accessed.

The second possibility is to create a clustered index with `minutes` as the first key.  You case probably does not warrant a clustered index, but that would also limit the database to only reading the data it needs to.